# How to get and remove the parentNode of querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I am trying to target the parent node, which is a div of a link tag(a) in my code, I have tried `target.parentNode` but that does not work, maybe as I am using querySelectorAll?. My code so far is:

```
  function remove() {
    var target = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-type="data"]'), i;
     for (i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
       if (target.length > 1) {
        target[i].remove();
       }
     }
  }
  remove();
```

Html:

```
<div class="carousel-slide">
   <a data-type="data" data-type="image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="./285-603.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Could you show the `HTML` part?

Comment: updated with the html

Comment: Is it just a single element that you're trying to delete or multiple ones?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: multiple ones  based on that a tag attribute

Comment: No Jquery, pure JS

Comment: `$(document)` looks like jQuery. Is there a reason you are using it here, but not anywhere else?

Comment: I have amended that now

Comment: "I have tried target.parentNode but that does not work" What happens when you do this? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue when you are doing `querySelectorAll` you do no need to define the `i`

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will get all `a[data-type="data"]` and the function will remove from the nodes from the DOM

**Edit:** To delete parent just your `parentNode.remove()` just use forEach function to get all `a` tags and remove its parents.

Run snippet below.

```js
function remove() {
  var target = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-type="data"]');
  target.forEach(function(anchors) {
    anchors.parentNode.remove();
    console.log('a tag with [data-type="data"] = Deleted')
  })
}
remove();
```

```html
<div class="carousel-slide">
   <a data-type="data" data-type="image">
   <img class="img-responsive" draggable="false">
   Will be deleted
   </a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-slide">
   <a data-type="no" data-type="image">
   <img class="img-responsive" draggable="false">
   Will stay
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to remove the parentNode (Div) being the Carousel Slide

Comment: @Sole Let me update the answer. You added HTML later.

Comment: @Sole See my updated answer. Working as you wanted with simplified code.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize `for...of` to loop through all elements that were found, then call `parentNode.remove()` on them:

```js
function remove() {
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-type='data']");
  console.log("before", anchors.length);

  // use `for...of` to iterate through all anchor tags
  for (var anchor of anchors) {
    // remove the parent node
    anchor.parentNode.remove();
  }
  
  console.log(
    "after", 
    document.querySelectorAll("a[data-type='data']").length
  );
}
remove();
```

```html
<div class="carousel-slide">
  <a data-type="data" data-type="image">
    <img
      class="img-responsive"
      draggable="false"
      src="./285-602.jpg"
    />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-slide">
  <a data-type="data" data-type="image">
    <img
      class="img-responsive"
      draggable="false"
      src="./285-603.jpg"
    />
  </a>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [for...of - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

```
const remove = () => {
  const target = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-type="data"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i].parentNode.remove();
  }
};
remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `target.parentNode` doesn't work is because `target` is an array of DOM elements. Array's don't have a `parentNode`. On the other hand each element in the array does:

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-type="data"]'), i;
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    console.log(target[i].parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  btnParent = document.querySelector('#parents');
  btnParent.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].parentNode.remove();
    }
  });
  
  btnWrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
  btnWrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    if (links && links.length > 0) {
      links[0].parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    } else {
      console.log('Nothing to delete');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  <button id="parents">Delete Parents</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button id="wrapper">Delete Wrapper</button>
  </p>
  <div style="background: red; padding: 20px; display: block;">
  <p>Wrapper</p>
  <div style="background: blue; padding: 20px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p>Parent</p>
    <a style="background: yellow; padding: 20px; display: block;" href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; padding: 20px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p>Parent</p>
    <a style="background: yellow; padding: 20px; display: block;" href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; padding: 20px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p>Parent</p>
    <a style="background: yellow; padding: 20px; display: block;" href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; padding: 20px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p>Parent</p>
    <a style="background: yellow; padding: 20px; display: block;" href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```